# Use Library Dependency Inputs as a cl compiler option/flag msvc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

So I am building my c++ project from the command line (just quicker for me to develop in) by doing `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"` and then using the `cl` compiler. So with my project, I need to link in a static library to my project that has static global initializers in it (that have side effects). I found that I can use `-WHOLEARCHIVE:libname.lib` to get it to work however this bloats the .exe file. When doing my research I found in the properties settings of any c++ project in the linker setting there is a `Use Library Dependency Inputs` option which you can set to true (which if I understand right actually understands the dependency chain on global constructors and doesn't just dump every single thing from the library into the .exe).

So what `cl` compiler option/flag is equivalent to the linker option `Use Library Dependency Inputs`?

Comment: Use `MSBuild` .

Comment: @PaulSanders ok, but that doesn't answer the question. If I switched to `MSBuild` how would I do `Use Library Dependency Inputs`. "Use `MSBuild`", isn't a very descriptive or helpful especially since you are basically saying "migrate your entire build system"

Comment: Do you have a `.vcxproj`?  If so, `MSBuild` can build it from the command line.

Comment: @PaulSanders I do not with the project I am doing the command line compiling with

Comment: Oh, OK, well MSBuild would require one.  Might be worth setting one up, it's not difficult.  Visual Studio Community is a free download and should do the job.

Comment: "Use Library Dependency Inputs" is an instruction to the build system, not to the compiler or linker; it doesn't directly correspond to any linker option. It arranges the build so that the original .obj files that went into the .lib are passed to the linker, not the .lib file itself. The build system looks inside the static library project to come up with this list of .obj files. You can simulate this on the command line by manually listing the .obj files on the linker's command line. I'm not even sure it'd help with your present issue; the documentation says it helps with incremental linking.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do I just list the .obj files inside of the static .lib or how does the compiler know about the .obj inside the .lib?

Comment: Far as I can tell, explicitly listing all .obj files on the linker command line is what "Use Library Dependency Inputs" does.